# How can I get the position of an iframe using js in the iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The code may seem like this:

```
<!--index.htm-->
<iframe src="abc.htm"></iframe>
```

and abc.htm is which I can control, now I want to know the position of the iframe in the page index.htm，and how can I do? I cannot code in the index.htm.

I use `window.parent`, but I cannot get the top window, for the cross-domain issue, so what can I do to reach my goal?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the element position using JavaScript for top and left.

Just add Id to your `iframe` or if you don't want then select that using `document.querySelector()`.

```
<iframe src="abc.htm" id = "el"></iframe>

var el = document.getElementById("el");
el.innerHTML = el.offsetTop +" " +el.offsetLeft;
console.log("Top :" + el.offsetTop +" " +"Left :" +el.offsetLeft);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this, but as I said, I cannot control `index.htm`, and what I can code is in the file `abc.htm`. So could I reach my goal?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle kind of live example of code.